# Style guide for Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, writing-style

Style – and consistent style, at that – is **an essential part of good documentation**.

I see two aspects to this.

1. **Formatting**
2. **Writing style**

I hope, with this question, to find some consensus.

---

## Formatting

- Should **key words** be placed in bold? Or *italics*? Is there a danger of overuse?

> Subroutines are created by using the keyword `sub` followed by an
>   identifier and a code block enclosed in braces.
>
> **Subroutines** are created by using the keyword `sub` followed by an
>   **identifier** and a **code block** enclosed in braces.

- Should **methods** and **statements** be given in `monotype`? What about things like `STDIN` (or STDIN)? (Or perhaps sᴛᴅɪɴ.)
- Where possible, should code examples include the explanation?

```
my $filename = '/path/to/file';

open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Failed to open file: $filename"; 

# You can then either read the file one line at a time...
while(chomp(my $line = <$fh>)) {
    print $line . "\n";
}

# ...or read whole file into an array in one go
chomp(my @fileArray = <$fh>);
```

---

## Writing style

This, I am sure, will be much harder to agree on – so I'll steer clear of the *really* subjective stuff.

- Is using **non-American English** OK?

  For example: you may have noticed that I use **en dashes** – like this – with spaces around them (a British trait), whereas Americans use **em dashes**—like this—with no spaces.
- Should a style guide like **[plain English](http://www.plainenglish.co.uk/files/howto.pdf)** be used?

  (Plain English is a guide to writing in a simple, easily understandable way. Do not confuse *simple* with *boring*!)

  For example,

  > Access to the arguments passed is accomplished using the special variable `@_`, which contains all arguments as an array.

  might become

  > You can access the arguments by using the special variable `@_`, which contains all arguments as an array.

  which is simpler and clearer.

Comment: There are millions of ways to write. I could have also said, "The arguments can be accessed by using the special..." All three are equally valid. None of this style business matters, as long as it's clear and reasonable. Spell it color or colour, use spaces with your dashes or no spaces (plz don't use hyphens as dashes tho, omgwtf), just make it look like something you'd be proud of. We cannot possibly hope to govern this, even if we agreed on Meta on some kind of master style. Edit if you see something that looks bad.

Comment: @CodyGray; a fair point! Given the length of your comment, do you want to put that in an answer? (Along the lines of ‘if it looks bad, edit it’.)

Comment: How about "Should 'keywords' be spelled as a single word or two?" ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think it'd be great to have a style guide. Even a very basic one like the ones that you find in the front matter of technical books (Sitepoint, O'Reilly, etc).

In addition, because the Documentation area is supposed to be example-laden, I'd also at least love to see the style guide emphasize the following rule:

- To mean "**For example**," use: ***E.g.***
- To mean "**In other words**" or "**That is to say**," use: ***I.e.***

Every time I see the erroneous usage of "I.e." (and there are a lot of these...) it irks me to near-death, but I don't want to bug people with the tiny copy edit (and don't want to appear as if I'm trying to inflate my reputation with minor, inconsequential edits).

Comment: In my opinion, if you're saying "For example", it's already too wordy. Concision and clarity are what matter. There are language-specific style issues, though: https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com%2Fdocumentation+%22meta:+documentation+guidelines%22

Comment: Huh? I never proposed using "For example." I proposed using either "e.g." or "i.e.", _correctly_.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I am saying: use neither Latin nor English here -- don't write it at all. Find an editor or learn how to be concise. I should have said in my first comment "If you want to say 'for example', ...."

Comment: I disagree so strongly. E.g.,'s come in very handy for sentence-level definitions or explanations... e.g., this one. 

Or the following one: (picked randomly from Microsoft's website)

"Use a period as a directory component in a path to represent the current directory, for example ".\temp.txt". For more information, see Paths."

Comment: And it would be insanely restrictive to tell users not to use any form of "for example." So that brings me back to my **original point**: Isn't "e.g., `.\temp.txt`" about a thousand times nicer than "i.e., `.\temp.txt`"?

Comment: Yeah, well, clearly people can disagree about style. For instance, that's what we're doing right now. (See what I did there, with that redundant sentence? :) ) I think regulating it, especially by insisting on the use of Latin by folks for whom English is not their first language, is a hopeless pursuit. If you want to discuss more, the docs room people are game, I'm sure: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117558/documentation-public-beta